# Got 800A01AD error when using vbs to create Chilkat XML object

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript, rss, chilkat

My VB script got an error when using Windows Server 2003:

> Code "800A01AD"
>   Message "ActiveX component can't create object: 'Chilkat.Rss'"

The following line causes the error:

```
Set rss = CreateObject("Chilkat.Rss")
```

but it works fine when using Windows Vista.

How can I solve this problem in windows server 2003?

Simple Code: http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/rss_read_feed.asp
Chilkat XML: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/XML-ActiveX.asp

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveX component can't create object: 'X'` error means that the library has not been installed on the machine you are attempting to run your code on.

You will need to install the dll (or msi/exe if it has one) which contains the Chillkat.Rss assembly on your windows server 2003 machine.

[More information here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319844)

Comment: i installed Chilkat XML already.......and tested on two machines, one is vista, other is server 2003, and run the same code, but only work fine on vista that one....